# Network file systems to store static images/files

Tags: filesystems, distributed

I think the problem is quite common: you have a website where people can upload images/files onto it, which could be thousands everyday. So what is the best network file system (distributed file system) that could handle the problem, especially the scalability. Specially,

1. It must be well distributed over different nodes. Nodes aren't needed much of fault-recovery.
2. Mostly read and write, no update.
3. There're some simple Client libraries for write/read.

I've studied the Hadoop file system and it seems that it's not the good way as it's about managing big files for Map-Reduce, not for millions of small files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at your requirements:

> - One image should be stored on a one node. Otherwise, if it is partitioned, image response latency could drop down dramatically
> - Fault tolerance is not the case

Why would you go with a distributed file system in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean a distributed file system? I am posting the question to ask about a specific type of DFS, at least a common DFS that people are using.

It shouldn't be rsync or any similar "manual" ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think MogileFs would be the good choice for you. But it has redundancy if you set it.

https://github.com/mogilefs/